# What is Authorization Endpoint UR L of Netsuite

Tags: oauth, netsuite

I am trying to connect to Netsuite Via Webservices, using Oauth utilizing Soap Webservices:

Tool i am using is asking for following three piece of info:
Authorization Endpoint URL:
Token Endpoint URL:
Web Service URL:

Where can i find following info:

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

The web service URL is:

`https://webservices.netsuite.com/services/NetSuitePort_2016_1`

The WSDL URL is:

`https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2016_1_0/netsuite.wsdl`

If you follow the link below, there are sample applications that use Apache Axis to invoke their APIs via SOAP.

References:

http://www.netsuite.com/portal/developers/resources/suitetalk-sample-applications.shtml

Comment: For Twitter is would be as following:
Authorization Endpoint: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize
Token Endpoint: https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token

Is ther something similar to that, how does Netsuite Handle Authorization when we user Token based authentication?

Comment: It seems like there's been a misunderstanding.  If you want to use OAuth, you need to use their REST API.  See the section "Using OAuth in the Authorization Header" here: https://system.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=51416823&c=NLCORP&h=c7cecd8e1180e6076aca&_xt=.pdf

Comment: Cant we use SOAP with Oauth in netsuite using TBA? Netsuite has a sample visual studio application utilizing soap web services to connect with system using token based auth.

Comment: Does Netsuite Support Oauth2.0?